Git bash stops responding in VS Code
Git Bash stops responding in VSCode after backspace is hit at $ Also it stops responding after two or three commands are executed.
Git bash outside VSCode works fine.
It also works properly with IntelliJ IDE.
I have to kill the git bash terminal and start a new terminal for it to respond again.
Other terminals powershell, cmd work fine as well

